# Convert SID to GUID in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I Want to get the GUID value from the given Sid value in Ad active directory and groups.

```
class Program
{
    static string myGuid;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myGuid = GetGuidString("S-1-5-21-1520874019-1059933425-2350978085-6519");

        Console.WriteLine(myGuid);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static string GetGuidString(string sid)
    {
        return Guid.Parse(sid).ToString();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Emh... a SID is not even close to the format of a GUID (which is like `F9168C5E-CEB2-4faa-B6BF-329BF39FA1E4`). What exactly do you want to get as result?

Comment: [SID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier#Identifier_Authority_Values)-> `S-1-5-21-3623811015-3361044348-30300820-101` [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)-> `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaurav/2014/06/03/security-identifiersid-getsid-of-a-userobject-using-registry-wmic-powershell/

Comment: I'm not getting the ObjectGuid value from AD, Is there any way we can achieve the GUID from the returned object having ObjectSId.

Comment: I'm working on Mac profile creation of Login window payload that using Guid for Access(allow/deny) of users.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf you can see the reference here AllowList and DenyList is taking Guid value

Comment: I'm not sure how is that related to Active Directory, but I can assure you that the SID is not what you want if you need a GUID

Comment: A SID can be up to 68 bytes in length. A guid is 16 bytes long (always). Do you see a problem yet?

Comment: Fellas, he's talking about active directory, not 'I wanna convert base64 to rot13'. I've answered the question already, but not everyone is willing to jump the hurdle of reading vb :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to query active directory. Here's a vb solution, you can either translate it or just look into the System.DirectoryServices namespace.

```
'example sid: S-1-5-21-2407707581-4260124077-1944392116-13936
Function getGuidFromSid(ByVal sid As String) As String
    Dim rootEntry As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry()
    Dim searcher As New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(rootEntry)
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(New String() {"sAMAccountName", "objectGUID"})
    searcher.Filter = "(&(objectSid=" & sid & ")(objectCategory=person))"
    Dim results As DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection
    results = searcher.FindAll()
    Dim ret = results.Item(0).Properties("objectGUID").Item(0) 'quick and dirty, please handle nulls etc
    Return ret
End Function
```

Comment: Which package you are installing for this service "DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry()"

Comment: Package? It's System.DirectoryServices, a built-in that you may need to add a reference to